# Kill Running Threads from ThreadPool When the RecyclerView Scrolls

Tags: android, optimization, android-recyclerview, threadpool

I have `ThreadPool` which fetches video thumbnail from a remote url. I am showing this thumbnail in a `RecyclerView`, the `ThreadPool` works as expected. I am starting this task from `onBindViewHolder` of `RecyclerView` `Adapter`. The issue is, suppose if I have 100 tasks, and scrolled down to the 100th item (last), then thread has to wait until the 99 has to be processed. so what I need is when the user scrolls I have to cancel other tasks which is not required to show in the screen, and should start the new tasks. how can I do that, any help will be appreciated.

ThreadPool class

```
public static VideoThumbnailThreadPoolManager getInstance() {

public void downloadThumbnail(String url, DownloadCompleteListener listener) {
        mExecutor.execute(new ImageDownloaderThread(url, listener));
  }


 private class ImageDownloaderThread extends Thread {
        String mUrl;
        DownloadCompleteListener mListener;

        ImageDownloaderThread(String url, DownloadCompleteListener listener) {
            setName(url);
            mUrl = url;
            mListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Bitmap thumbnail = GeneralUtils.retriveVideoFrameFromVideo(mUrl);
                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onThumbnailDownloaded(thumbnail);
                }
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                throwable.printStackTrace();

                if (mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onThumbnailDownloaded(null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void killThreadBy(String name) {
    //Give you set of Threads
    Set<Thread> setOfThread = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();

    //Iterate over set to find yours
    for (Thread thread : setOfThread) {
        if (thread.getName().equals(name)) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    }
}

}
```

**Edit**

I am not getting a thumbnail url, I am generating thumbnail by taking first frame of the video.

**NB**

Do not recommend Picasso, Glide... as it cannot load thumbnail from a remote video url.

Comment: You can use Picasso, which is excellently works with recyclerView(it manages the images downloading exactly as you want)

Comment: I do not have a image url, I am generating thumbnail from video url, so picasso, glide wont help

Comment: so what you are receiving from the web api? if not a Bitmap, then what is it?

Comment: its a video, I am taking the first frame of that video and showing it as thumbnail

Comment: sending ? I am not sending anything, I am just taking one frame from the video which is located in the server.

Comment: sure: receiving, so how are you taking one frame from a remote server? whats the format of that frame? how are you converting that frame to a `Bitmap`?

Comment: We can get it as bitmap, refer this link : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28%29

Comment: and what  `setDataSource` are you using?

Comment: obviously video url

Comment: its better to use an asynctask for this approach. You can load the bitmaps off the thread & cancel the asycntask which are not needed after scroll. You can refer this-
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

Comment: Creating new asynctask each time is very costly, thats why I've created threadpool

Comment: use `ThreadPoolExecutor` and its `submit(Runnable task)` method which returns `java.util.concurrent.Future` that can be canceled in `Adapter#onViewRecycled`

Comment: I implemented already, thanks

Comment: and your `ImageDownloaderThread extends Thread` should be just `ImageDownloaderThread implements Runnable` - and of course `ImageDownloaderThread` should be something like `ImageDownloaderRunnable`

Comment: that also I have changed, initially I have used Thread so that I can set name and identify later to terminate. instead now I am keeping a Map which keeps all the Runnable created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer.

I am removing the task when onViewRecycled() method calls,

```
     @Override
     public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
      if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
                MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
        String threadName = holder.itemView.getTag();

        if(notEmpty(threadName)){
          executor.remove(getRunnableFromName(threadName));
        }
       }
   }
```

Comment: just use `submit(Runnable task)` inside `onBindViewHolder` and store the `Futore` in some `ViewHolder` field like `holder.future = tpe.submit(...)` and in `onViewRecycled` just call `holder.future.cancel()`, that's all

Comment: can you explain more ? add some more code if you can

Comment: what to explain? add a field `Future future` to your `Holder`, call `submit(..)` inside `onBindViewHolder` and `holder.future.cancel()` in `onViewRecycled`

Comment: will check that. :)

Comment: can you share your full answer how can we remove runnable or thread?